# Can we construct the general solution by separation of variables of linear PDEs?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider a linear PDE of the form
$$f(x) u_x + g(y) u_y + h(x) u = 0.$$
This PDE is separable as $u=X(x) Y(y)$ to obtain
$$f(x) X' + (h(x) + K) X =0,$$
$$g(y)Y' - K Y =0,$$
where $K$ is an integration constant. Let us assume that we can obtain a general solution for $X$ and $Y$ dependent on $K$ and two other integration constants $X_0, Y_0$. Then, we can construct other solutions for $u$ by summing (integrating over) $XY$ with different $X_0,Y_0,K$ because the PDE is linear.

But can we construct a general solution in this way? I.e., is there a solution to the PDE above which *cannot* be constructed by superposing $XY$ for different $X_0,Y_0,K$?

Comment: Is there not a sign mistake in : $$f(x) X' + (h(x) + K) X =0,$$
$$g(y)Y' + K Y =0,$$ which should be : $$g(y)Y' - K Y =0$$

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions obtained thanks the "separation of variables" method will be compared to the solutions obtained thanks to the method of "characteristics".

METHOD OF CHARACTEISTICS :

[image]

METHOD OF SEPARAION OF VARIABLES :

[image]

The form of the result is the same as with the method of characteristics. But the content isn't exactly the same. With the method of separation of variables, the functions $F(z)$ involved are those which can be discretized on the form :
$$F(z)=\sum C_\lambda e^{\lambda z} \qquad \text{any constants } \lambda \text{ and }C_\lambda$$

In order to avoid the question of discretization, alternatively a continuous form of solution is derived from the method of separation of variables :

[image]

Again, the form of the result is the same as with the method of characteristics. The function $F(z)$ involved is any function which can be expressed on integral form:
$$F(z)=\int C(\lambda) e^{\lambda z}d\lambda$$
where $C(\lambda)$ is any function.